# Average model from different runs

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I am using gradient boosting classifier to classify data into two class. Let's say spam/non spam.

At different thresholds, I am getting different confusion matrixes. I am interested in the TN vs FN curve.

I ran the classifier 10 times with different seeds as I wanted to report a robust number.

But I am confused about how to take average and measure standard deviation of these 10 runs.

I have taken 10k threshold values. Should I take mean and std on grouping threshold?

Edit: what I mean is, should I take 5 threshold value and check the deviation among all 10 results. And then pick man to report if standard deviation is low there.